# issue: href links on top of each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

The href links on my website are directly on top of each other - instead of being vertically on top of each other. I tried adding 'positon: relative' but it didn't work.

Here's the HTML:

```css
div.footer {
  background-color: #8dcab3ff;
  /* Dark Teal */
  color: #ffffff;
  /* White */
  padding: 25px 0px;
  width: fill;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.inner_footer {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner_footer .logo_container {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner_footer .logo_container img {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
}

.inner_footer .footer_third {
  width: calc(21.666667% - 20px);
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
}

.inner_footer .footer_third:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="inner_footer">
    <!-- Footer content starts here -->
    <div class="logo_container">
      <img src="images/14_logo.png">
    </div>

    <div class="footer_third">
      <h5>Information
        <h5>
          <a href="#"> Privacy Policy </a>
          <a href="#"> Copyright</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer content ends here -->
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I see one issue that might be related: your `h5` tag is not closing

Comment: thanks! that did help

Answer (score -1):

Try This,
Html:

```html
<ul id="mainMenu">
  <li><a href="#"> Privacy Policy </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"> Copyright</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
#mainMenu {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 900px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#mainMenu li {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#mainMenu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #009;
}

#mainMenu a:hover {
  background-color: #009;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want your  tags to be next to each other, you need to allow space for them to be next to each other. At the moment, you only have a width of 21.66%Maybe post a screenshot if that is not what you mean or need

```css
div.footer {
  background-color: #8dcab3ff;
  /* Dark Teal */
  color: #ffffff;
  /* White */
  padding: 25px 0px;
  width: fill;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.inner_footer {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner_footer .logo_container {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner_footer .logo_container img {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
}

.inner_footer .footer_third {
  width: calc(61.666667% - 20px);
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner_footer .footer_third a {
     display: inline-block; 
     margin-right: 10px;
}
.inner_footer .footer_third:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="inner_footer">
    <!-- Footer content starts here -->
    <div class="logo_container">
      <img src="images/14_logo.png">
    </div>

    <div class="footer_third">
      <h5>Information</h5>

          <a href="#"> Privacy Policy </a>
          <a href="#"> Copyright</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer content ends here -->
  </div>

</div>
```